# Simple way to check for membership in a list?

Tags: swift2

For use in a closure (though I suppose it will be useful elsewhere as well), what is the cleanest way to check to see whether or not a given element is a member of a list (or any character is a member of a string)?

For example, to check whether or not the string `"abcde"` contains any of the characters in `"aeiou"`, or whether the list `["bill", "sam" , "suzy"]` contains any of the names in `["abe", "bill", "charlie"]`?

Comment: Would it be ok to cancel the search after the first match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1 ) Common chars in 2 words

You easily check the intersection of the common chars in 2 strings using the `Set` struct:

```
let set0 = Set("abcde".characters)
let set1 = Set("aeiou".characters)

let intersection = set0.intersect(set1) // {"e", "a"}
```

### 2) Common words in 2 lists

Similarly you can find the intersection of 2 arrays of strings:

```
let set0 : Set = ["bill", "sam", "suzy"]
let set1 : Set = ["abe", "bill", "charlie"]

let intersection = set0.intersect(set1) // {"bill"}
```

### 3) Back to Array

Please note that in both examples, the `intersection` constant is a `Set`. You can transform it into an Array writing:

```
let list = Array(intersection)
```

Hope this helps.

*P.S. This code is for Swift 2.0*

### Update

More specifically if you want to find out whether an intersection exists you can simply write:

```
 !intersection.isEmpty
```

Comment: This approach may lead to unexpected results if the arrays have duplicate elements.

Comment: Looking at the text of the question I still think this answer is correct: `For example, to check whether or not the string "abcde" contains any of the characters in "aeiou"`. However I updated my answer to get a boolean value indicating whether there is an intersection between the 2 lists.

Answer (score 2):

Swift arrays have built in functions for this exact functionality.

I recommend checking out the [official documentation for Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) from Apple for a starting point.

Here is an example that follows your question:

```
// With [Character]
let vowels: [Character] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
let chars: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let resultVowels = vowels.filter { chars.contains($0) }
resultVowels.count // == 2
resultVowels.description // == "[a, e]"

// With [String]
let people = ["Bill", "Sam", "Suzy"]
let peeps = ["Abe", "Bill", "Charlie"]
let resultPeople = people.filter { peeps.contains($0) }
resultPeople.count // == 1
resultPeople.description // == "[Bill]"
```

The result will be the names (or numbers, characters, etc.) that are matching up. So you can not only get the count, but also the contents of the comparison in this procedure. So long as the types follow Equatable, this will work for you.
If you want to return a Boolean, just simply:

```
return filteredArray.count != 0
```

Now, if you want to compare say, a [Character] to a String then:

```
let vowels: [Character] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
let someString = "abcde"
let result = vowels.filter { someString.characters.contains($0) }
result.count // == 2
result.description // == "[a, e]"
```

The String.characters property is a new feature brought in to Swift 2.

I hope I was able to assist you.

Comment: Great answer. I gave the checkmark to appzYourLife only because his approach is more concise, if I could have, I'd have given it to this answer as well.